# R - counting on two different conditions

Tags: r, aggregate

While I use Stackoverflow all the time, this is my first question so I hope it is enough detail.  Thanks in advance.

I am trying to provide some statistics from a large data set where I have a set of User IDs.  Each record in the data set is one Customer User ID.  I need to be able to summarize by Sales Rep...  # of User IDs per sales rep and # of customers per sales rep

```
sample <- data.frame(rep = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
             customer = c("A","A","A","B","C","X","X","Y"), 
             userID = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6","ID7","ID8"))
```

In this data set I would need to be able to say that:

```
Rep ID  --  # of Cust   -- # of IDs
Rep 1   --  3 customers --  5 IDs
Rep 2   --  2 customers --  3 IDs
```

I was going about doing this by putting together 2 tables, but it isn't quite getting me there...  `data.frame(table(paste(sample$rep,sample$customer)))`  gives me a very manual way of deriving my answer.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `aggregate(.~rep, df, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))` if you want unique counts

Comment: @docendodiscimus Your comment counts as an answer, please post it as such (along with a little expaination).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to reflect @Lamia comment, it simplifies the code by using a nice built in `dplyr` function.

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>% group_by(rep) %>% summarize(customer = n_distinct(customer),
                                       user = n_distinct(userID))
```

Output:

```
    rep customer  user
  <dbl>    <int> <int>
1     1        3     5
2     2        2     3
```

Comment: You can also replace `length(unique))` by `n_distinct()`.

Comment: Thank you - this got me exactly what I wanted